# Select an XML node via XPath at an arbitrary depth

Tags: c#, xml, xpath, wix

Having an XML document, I want to get the first node with a certain name, no matter in which nesting depth it is contained.

I tried several things without success:

```
var node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//Shortcut");
var node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/*/Shortcut");
var node3 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//*/Shortcut");
var node4 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"*/Shortcut");
...
```

Each call results in a `NULL` node.

I think it should be some trivial XPath syntax. Can you help me?

(In case this matters: The XML document is an input file for a [WiX](http://wix.sourceforge.net/) project, so there could be some namespace issues involved?!?).

**Edit**

I also tried the following:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace(string.Empty, @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
nsm.AddNamespace(@"ns", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
```

together with:

```
var node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//Shortcut", nsm);
var node2 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"/*/Shortcut", nsm);
var node3 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//*/Shortcut", nsm);
var node4 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"*/Shortcut", nsm);
...
```

Leading to the same results.

**Edit 2 - Solution**

I found the solution:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace(string.Empty, @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
nsm.AddNamespace(@"ns", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
```

and then

```
var node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//ns:Shortcut", nsm);
```

This succeeded.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for a more general and flexible solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The XPath expression that selects exactly the wanted node (and nothing in addition) is**:

```
(//x:Shortcut)[1]
```

So, using:

```
doc.SelectNodes("(//x:Shortcut)[1]", someNamespaceManager)
```

where

the prefix `"x"` is bound to the namespace `"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi"`

in `someNamespaceManager`

**This has an advantage over the proposed solution (to use `SelectSingleNode()`), because it can easily be adjusted to select the N-th wanted node in the XML document**.

For example:

```
   (//x:Shortcut)[3]
```

selects the 3rd (in document order) `x:Shortcut` element, and

```
   (//x:Shortcut)[last()]
```

selects the last (in document order) `x:Shortcut` element in the XML document.

Comment: I do understand the improvement of the XPath expression but I don't understand why you suggest to use it with `SelectNodes` instead of `SelectSingleNode`. Clearly with the path expression being written to select a single node with a positional predicate you can just as well pass it to SelectSingleNode.

Comment: @Martin Honnen: `SelectSingleNode()` helps the OP select the 1st node out of `//someName` -- it always selects the 1st node only. I wanted to show him that he doesn't need this feature of `SelectSingleNode()` because he can specify in the XPath expression itself exactly which node or nodes he needs. Then, he will not have (be obliged) to use `SelectSingleNode()`. I am not saying he mustn't use `SelectSingleNode()` -- only that he is now free not to use it.

Answer (score 2):

Why do not use [XDocument](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.linq.xdocument.aspx)?

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Load("test.xml");
doc.Descendants("Shortcut").First();
```

IMO XDocument is faster and more readable than XPath.

Comment: Thanks. What kind of class is `XDocument`? From a custom class?

Comment: @Uwe Keim, I'd added reference link.

Comment: @Uwe Keim: it's part of [Linq-to-XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx) first introduced in .NET 3.0 (VS 2008)

Answer (score 2):

I finally found the solution by myself:

```
var nsm = new XmlNamespaceManager(doc.NameTable);
nsm.AddNamespace(string.Empty, @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
nsm.AddNamespace(@"ns", @"http://schemas.microsoft.com/wix/2006/wi");
```

and then

```
var node1 = doc.SelectSingleNode(@"//ns:Shortcut", nsm);
```

This succeeded.