# Whats wrong with my XPath?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xpath, xml-parsing

I try to parse this XML file (config file from [Chirpy](http://chirpy.codeplex.com/)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<root xmlns="urn:ChirpyConfig" 
     xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
     xsi:schemaLocation="urn:ChirpyConfig http://www.weirdlover.com/chirpy/chirp.xsd">
     <FileGroup Name="Built.debug.js" Minify="false">
        <File Path="jquery/jquery-1.7.2.js"/>
        <File Path="jquery.address/jquery.address-1.4.js"  />
    </FileGroup>
</root>
```

with this code:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/ScriptfilesMashup.chirp.config");
var file = new XPathDocument(path);
var nav = file.CreateNavigator();
var nodes = nav.Select("/root/FileGroup/File");
```

but `nodes` is always empty, regardless of how I call the `nav.Select` method. I barely used XPath before so maybe I'm doing it wrong - but what? Only the selector `*` gives me the root node.

What would be the selector to get the `Path` Attribute of all `File` nodes?

**EDIT: SOLUTION**

Thanks to Kirill, the final solution looks like this:

```
var path = Server.MapPath("~/Scripts/ScriptfilesMashup.chirp.config");
var file = new XPathDocument(path);
var nav = file.CreateNavigator();
var ns = "urn:ChirpyConfig";

XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", ns);

var nodes = nav.Select("/x:root/x:FileGroup/x:File/@Path", nsMgr);    
while(nodes.MoveNext())
{
    var path = nodes.Current.Value;
}
```

Comment: I had a similar issue in the past when I was ignoring the fact, that there is an XML namespace involved. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6635108/107625) to my question as a possible hint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is because elements `root`, `FileGroup` and `File` are defined in `urn:ChirpyConfig` namespace.

Use this:

```
XPathDocument xmldoc = new XPathDocument(xmlFile);
XPathNavigator nav = xmldoc.CreateNavigator();
XmlNamespaceManager nsMgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsMgr.AddNamespace("x", "urn:ChirpyConfig");
XPathNavigator result = nav.SelectSingleNode("/x:root/x:FileGroup/x:File", nsMgr);
```

Comment: Thanks very much, I didn't know that it was namespace related. But your code gives me only one node but I need all `Path` attributes in a string list, how can I do that?

Comment: @Marc, You're welcome. Use `Select` instead of `SelectSingleNode`: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0ea193ac.aspx

Comment: Yeah, I tried that but I figured out that I have to change the XPath to `/x:root/x:FileGroup/x:File/@Path`. Thanks again, I will post the final solution.